# Make downloads dock icon bounce programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, dock, bounce

How can I make the dock Downloads icon bounce programmatically? 
Notice that I don't want my app icon to bounce, but only Downloads' icon.

In particular, I'm downloading a file from my app to Downloads folder. No problem with this, but I want the Downloads icon to bounce when the download is finished (as happen when Safari completes a download).

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Be more specific about what you are trying to do. I think you mean you want to force the Mac OS X Download Folder on the dock to bounce? I very much doubt that is possible.

Comment: I've added some information, however you understood exactly the point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick Google search turns up

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        postNotificationName:@"com.apple.DownloadFileFinished"
        object:pathToFile];
```

from http://iloveco.de/quick-trick-bouncing-the-downloads-stack/

I think the trick for knowing what to search for was knowing that the folders in the Dock have been called ["Stacks"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacks_%28software%29) since 10.5.