# Bounce the Downloads Stack in Dock programmatically …

Tags: swift, macos

How can I make the dock Downloads stack bounce programmatically? I don't want to bounce my app's icon.

I found this Solution for Objective-C on the Web:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"com.apple.DownloadFileFinished" object:pathToFile];
```

And changed them to a Swift-Pedant, but this doesn't work:

```
let defaultCenter = DistributedNotificationCenter ()    
defaultCenter.postNotificationName(NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "com.apple.DownloadFileFinished"), object: file.absoluteString, userInfo: nil, deliverImmediately: true)
```

I'm using Swift 5 for a Mac App and macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

In particular, I'm downloading a file from my app to Downloads folder. No problem with this, but I want the Downloads icon to bounce when the download is finished (as happen when Safari completes a download).

Comment: The translated code would be `DistributedNotificationCenter.default().post(name: NSNotification.Name("com.apple.DownloadFileFinished") object: file.path)`. Give that a try.

Comment: There's still no Error in the Log and it doesn't work. Maybe Apple has changed the NSNotificationName for this ?

Comment: Well the Objective-C code shown at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8342974/20287183) is over 11 years old. macOS has changed a lot in that time.

Comment: Ok, small Update: I found the "com.apple.DownloadFileFinished" in Function bounceDownloadsFolderInDock() inside the Plash-App: https://github.com/sindresorhus/Plash/blob/main/Plash/Utilities.swift. Since this App is for newer Macs and running on macOS 10.15 and higher it should still be available. I found the String also in Safari.framework …

Comment: That code shows the same code I posted in my earlier comment. So perhaps the code is correct but the URL you are using isn’t correct.

Comment: I managed it to get it working by replacing a Part of the url.path with `url.path.replacingOccurrences(of: "Library/Containers/<bundleidoftheapp>/Data/", with: "")` …

Comment: You should post an answer below showing your complete solution.

Comment: It appears that "com.apple.DownloadFileFinished" only works in non-sandboxed apps.